# Enhanced Email logging email matched records

Tags: email, outlook, enhanced-emails

I have a User base that uses the Outlook Integration heavily (I know this is retiring soon anyway btw) - I'm struggling to find out how this '**Other**' section matches SF records. It looks to be pulling in Account records - but the record it always pulls in is the same one that seems to be unrelated to the actual email. (Bunker) We checked the record in question and made sure none of its email addresses matched anything inside the email thread.

Is this panel configurable - i cant tell if the record is an actual Account record or maybe its a child record related to Account. We have many child object of the Account so it will be hard to got through them all?[image]